# Include/Require question in PHP

Tags: php, include

Is there a way of including functions like "include()" or function("") but runs the file (assuming another php file) as though it is an entirely private program and does not pass the information between the main code and the included code?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you give an example of intended use? There might be a better way to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Daniel below was right. I was hoping to run a script from within my php code so that the globals and functions within each would not affect the original code.  Obvious noob. Thanks - Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's any nice way to do this, but if you really need to, you can use

```
shell_exec("php $script");
```

Comment: thanks Daniel, I just used exec (instead of shell exec) and that was it.  For some reason I thought you couldn't run php scripts with shell_exec or exec.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can do something like:

```
`php -f /path/to/file.php`
```

Comment: @Alfred: OP asked about a way for running php in a clean environment, without any currently declared variables and functions. That is how I got the question